# When testing in SoapUI, requests take much longer than requests made in code. Why?

Tags: c#, .net, webclient, soapui

We are just about ready to move into load testing at work. The current setup involves some test cases created in SoapUI, but there's a problem.

When we run these test cases in code (C#, BCL WebClient, etc.), the average time for a request is between 0.1 and 0.15 seconds. These same tests, when run in SoapUI, run for *almost five seconds.*

I'm not a SoapUI guy, and our QA guy is actually pretty new to it, too. I was hoping someone here might know of some basic thing we have missed that could be causing these huge delays.

Edits: Our logging suggests that the actual response time is the same either way, but I didn't write that logging, so I don't know how correct it may or may not be. Time to serve requests sent by either method is a few dozen milliseconds.

Edits (Version 2! :): Ok, we were reading the logs incorrectly. There is a four second delay, but it has nothing to do with the request/response cycle. No idea what his test case is doing, but it's doing something that takes *forever* before it makes a request. Sorry guys. :)

Comment: Are you able to do any logging to verify that these calls are still only taking tenths of a second when run through SoapUI? I'm guessing the extra time is in the SoapUI application itself but that would be nice to verify.

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out. In Windows 8, if you have the proxy settings in SoapUI set to "Automatic," it spends like four seconds doing *nothing* before it does any work. If you set it to something else (in our case "None" or, presumably, your actual proxy?), it works just fine.

This behavior is not apparent in Windows 7. Hooray for software upgrades.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone facing this issue, I'd like to mention that this problem has been fixed in the latest version (4.6.4) of SoapUI.